# Display list of records from database in a nicer format than a table mvc asp.net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm looking for a nicer way to display a list of records from my database in views, instead of using a normal table and a "for each" loop, like this:

```
<table class="table">
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.date)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.name)
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.date)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.name)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.id }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.id }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.id })
    </td>
</tr>
}

</table>
```

Preferably I would like to display each record in a "profile" type format, something like this:

[profile image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aagha.png)

Comment: Sure. I'd suggest using a `dl` list instead of a table. More information about that list: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dl

Comment: That's an HTML question. If you google you'll find a lot of tutorials, control tools, Javascript libraries that do that using divs, CSS classes, Javascript. A table row doesn't have to contain *cells*, nor does `@foreach` have to create *tables*. Check [the W3.CSS Cards](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_cards.asp) style for example, it allows you to create a card just with divs. Your `@foreach` could create such sections instead of table rows

Comment: Thanks to both of you!

Answer (score 1):

replace the dummy text with the properties from the model

```css
body{padding-top:30px;}

.glyphicon {  margin-bottom: 10px;margin-right: 10px;}

small {
display: block;
line-height: 1.428571429;
color: #999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!------ Include the above in your HEAD tag ---------->

<div class="container">
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
            <div class="well well-sm">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/380x500" alt="" class="img-rounded img-responsive" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-8">
                        <h4>
                            Bhaumik Patel</h4>
                        <small><cite title="San Francisco, USA">San Francisco, USA <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker">
                        </i></cite></small>
                        <p>
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i>email@example.com
                            <br />
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></i><a href="">www.jquery2dotnet.com</a>
                            <br />
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-gift"></i>June 02, 1988</p>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    }
</div>
```

Comment: you are welcome, kindly mark as correct answer if your happy with it.